# How to create hyphen alias for zsh?

Tags: zsh, alias, cd-command, oh-my-zsh

I am using [*zsh*](http://www.zsh.org) and [*oh-my-zsh*](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) on Ubuntu.

To change into the recent directory in the past there was an alias set to `-` which is the same as `cd -`. Somehow the alias disappeared at my machine. This might have happened due to updates I pulled from the *oh-my-zsh* repository.

Now, I would like to add this alias to my own dotfiles. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alias was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/commit/25b1cd687b28cb8d05229130ee5a0e2494276894).

To add it back:

```
alias -- -='cd -'
```

---

Most of POSIX shells need `--` for this alias work, only `dash` doesn't:

```
$ dash
$ alias -='echo 1'
$ -
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Like with any other command, use `--` to instruct the command that subsequent arguments beginning with `-` are not options.

```
alias -='cd -'
```

You may prefer to make `-` a function, to give it some use when it has arguments. In zsh, `-` is a [precommand modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Precommand-Modifiers), which runs a command with `-` prepended to the zeroth argument. (Granted, that's a little obscure, and you can use the [`ARGV0 variable`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-ARGV0) to achieve the same effect.) Unlike `alias`, `function` is not a built-in command but a keyword that doesn't take options, so you can use `function -`.

```
function - {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    cd "$OLDPWD"
  else
    builtin - "$@"
  fi
}
```

(Or whatever you want `- foo` to do.)